# Matlab crashes segmentation violation

Tags: 16.04, matlab, segmentation-fault

I am using MATLAB 2016b and it crashes due to segmentation violation every time i run some programs on it

Following is the error , could some one please help me with this problem

```
  could not create on-disk crash report: failed opening file: Too many open files

------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Mon Mar 20 15:39:11 2017
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Brian Paul Mesa X11 Version 2.1 Mesa 10.5.2
  Current Visual      : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  Deployed            : false
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : vasudev-OptiPlex-780
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: Unknown
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b
  MATLAB Version      : 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)
  OpenGL              : software
  Operating System    : Linux 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11804000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007fc444e01aff  RBX = 00007fc412b50d74
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 00007fc412b50e60
  RSP = 00007fc412b50d10  RBP = 00007fc412b50d30
  RSI = 0000000000002727  RDI = 834810ed7f23e808

   R8 = 00007fc412b50d40   R9 = 00007fc412b50d50
  R10 = 0000000000000133  R11 = 00007fc477a53260
  R12 = 00007fc4380a9778  R13 = 00007fc438129458
  R14 = 834810ed7f23e808  R15 = 00007fc4380b0ba0

  RIP = 00007fc40882e213  EFL = 0000000000010282

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007fc40882e213 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/libt2k.so+00209427
[  1] 0x00007fc4088298a0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/libt2k.so+00190624
[  2] 0x00000000e49cde30                                   <unknown-module>+00000000


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.


MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error
Killed
```